# Inserting HTML into a Twig from a REST Call

Tags: php, rest, symfony, twig

I am trying to call a REST api for Header, Footer and Meta data and place/render it as full content in a twig.  The closest that I have gotten is the html being displayed on the page instead of rendering the content despite having the raw tag in place.  I could have implemented that wrong.  The Developer Console shows the HTML with quotes around it like a string.  I have a proxy call file as a backup option, but I would rather have the page render all at once instead of render and then having Javascript/jQuery insert the html.  All of my searches yield intentionally printing the HTML on the page.

Comment: Sounds like your raw tag ought to deal with this, is it written correctly? `{{ sometext | raw }}`

Comment: How are you calling the Rest API? Are you assigning those results to variables and passing those to twig to be rendered, or are you just trying to do the call from within twig?